# Simple way to open Port for Transmission for a Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, port, bittorrent, tcpip

I am a complete noob when it comes to TCP/IP, but would like to open up my port for the Transmission bit torrent client on Snow Leopard Mac. Also, I am based in the UK if that has any relevance.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning off your Firewall from * » System Preferences » Security » Firewall*?

Comment: Yes, my firewall is off.

Comment: I believe you have to forward that port from your router then, if it doesn't work automatically. Have you configured that already? See also [PortForwardingGuide – Transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/PortForwardingGuide)

Comment: @slhck How can I solve it if I want that port to be accessible from outside? Let's say it's just one port 41000? (Though I've forwarded this port and a whole range of it from my router to my Mac's IP - both TCP and UDP. I have also selected Transmission to "allow incoming connections"). Sometimes the port is close sometimes open. Using a VPN though solves the problem. And once it starts working (torrent downloading) then it keeps on working even if I turn the VPN off. Why is this odd behaviour? Is it my ISP? Or something on my Mac or router?

Comment: @amar Sorry, not sure. Ideally your router would have UPnP configuration so that the client can automaically open a port. uTorrent can do that, but Transmission can't.